# How to wait for forEach to complete with asynchronous callbacks?

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, callback

Sample code:

```
Map<String, String> gg = {'gg': 'abc', 'kk': 'kojk'};

Future<void> secondAsync() async {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
  print("Second!");
  gg.forEach((key, value) async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
    print("Third!");
  });
}

Future<void> thirdAsync() async {
  await Future<String>.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 2));
  print('third');
}

void main() async {
  secondAsync().then((_) {
    thirdAsync();
  });
}
```

output

```
Second!
third
Third!
Third!
```

as you can see i want to use to wait until foreach loop of map complete to complete then i want to print `third`
expected Output

```
Second!
Third!
Third!
third
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`Iterable.forEach`, `Map.forEach`, and `Stream.forEach` are meant to execute some code on each element of a collection for *side effects*.  They take callbacks that have a `void` return type.  Consequently, **those `.forEach` methods *cannot* use any values returned by the callbacks**, including returned `Future`s.  If you supply a function that returns a `Future`, that `Future` will be lost, and you will not be able to be notified when it completes.  You therefore cannot wait for each iteration to complete, nor can you wait for all iterations to complete.

**Do NOT use `.forEach` with asynchronous callbacks.**

Instead, if you want to wait for each asynchronous callback *sequentially*, just use a normal `for` loop:

```dart
for (var mapEntry in gg.entries) {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
}
```

(In general, [I recommend using normal `for` loops over `.forEach`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65420010/) in all but special circumstances. [Effective Dart has a mostly similar recommendation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/usage#avoid-using-iterableforeach-with-a-function-literal).)

If you *really* prefer using `.forEach` syntax and want to wait for each `Future` in succession, you could use [`Future.forEach`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Future/forEach.html) (which *does* expect callbacks that return `Future`s):

```dart
await Future.forEach(
  gg.entries,
  (entry) => Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5)),
);
```

If you want to allow your asynchronous callbacks to run concurrently (and [*possibly* in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72543144/)), you can use [`Future.wait`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Future/wait.html):

```dart
await Future.wait([
  for (var mapEntry in gg.entries)
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5)),
]);
```

See https://github.com/dart-lang/linter/issues/891 for a request for an analyzer warning if attempting to use an asynchronous function as a `Map.forEach` or `Iterable.forEach` callback (and for a list of many similar StackOverflow questions).