# dart await all functions with one line code

Tags: flutter, dart

in my code, there are functions which do async operations. so I have marked these called functions as async in the function body, I am using `await` for all the async operations. Is there any clear way to do that?

For example, I want to wrap all async operations with **only one** `await` keyword:

```
    Future<void> _clearTables()async{
      await{
        dbHelper.deleteDailyQuestions();
        dbHelper.deletePureCards();
        dbHelper.deleteStudiedCards();
      }
    }
```

Comment: You either can use [`Future.forEach`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Future/forEach.html) if you want to wait for each `Future` in succession, or you can use [`Future.wait`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Future/wait.html) if you want to wait for all of them concurrently. Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63719805/

Comment: I was exactly looking for this kind of await block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should try to use RxDart operators like `swicthMap` or `concatMap`? It makes a lot of sense in front end development. You can learn it [here](https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/rxdart-using-map-operators-examples) or [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1VKjP6g8PRo). Depending of when you want to get value you should use proper operator. You can decide to get value if each of the function have finished or take the result from the fastest only. A lot of options here. My suggestion is to find your question related to JavaScript code and then reuse it in Dart.

Comment: why couldn't I think that way :D i think i need some sleep

Answer (score -1):

You can add await for all the future returning functions

```
    Future<void> _clearTables()async{
      await dbHelper.deleteDailyQuestions();
      await dbHelper.deletePureCards();
      await dbHelper.deleteStudiedCards();
    }
```

Comment: This would run the functions one at a time, I'm assuming the author is looking for a way to run them in parallel.