# how to close something before compiler thinks it is assigned a value, because closing can happen only in 2nd iteration of a loop

Tags: flutter, dart, compiler-errors

I receive the error `The non-nullable local variable 'box' must be assigned before it can be used.` for the following code.

```dart
int problemClass = -1;
problems.forEach((p) async {
      if (p.problemClassId != problemClass) {
        if (problemClass != -1)
          box.close();
        box = await Hive.openBox(kProblemBoxNames[p.problemClassId]!);
        problemClass = p.problemClassId;
      }
}
```

I am opening a Hive box in the first iteration (`box.close()`cannot be executed because `problemClass == -1`). If `problemClass` does not change, the box remains unchanged in the 2nd iteration. However, if `problemClass` does change, the box currently open is closed and another box is opened.

How do I get the compiler to understand my logic?!

Comment: You can fix your problem by declaring `box` as `late`.  However, your logic isn't correct since `box.close()` will never be called; all iterations will execute before `problemClass` is set to a different value. [*Never* use `Iterable.forEach` with an `async` callback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63719374/).  You also will need to separately call `box.close()`  after the final iteration.

Comment: Thanks, that made a difference. I don't see why the box.close() will never be called, but if you are right, I will find out during debugging.

One thing that make me wonder a few times: why do some respondents prefer to answer with a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: As I said, `box.close()` will not be called because `Iterable.forEach` is not meant to be used with `async` operations, and it is impossible for each iteration to wait for `Future`s from previous iterations to complete.  Therefore `problemClass` will be -1 for all iterations.  As for comment vs. answer: in this case, I didn't feel like writing a more extensive answer explaining *why*, and there likely are existing questions (and answers).

Comment: got it. I already changed from `.forEach` to `for (p in xy)`