# Flutter future full list returns null

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, future

I have a future method and it pulls data from firebase. Data comes in and adds to the list, but the list returns empty. Where ı am do wrong

```dart
  Future<List<String>> takipEdilenlerinFotolariniGetir() async {
    List<String> fotoUrller = [];
    //takip edilen 4 kişi seçilir.
    Query first = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("takiplesme")
        .doc('${FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid}')
        .collection('takipEdilenler')
        .limit(4);
    //sçeilen 4 kişinin idleri(döküman şeklinde) getirilir.
    var idler = await first.get();
    for (var id in idler.docs) {
      //fotograflari gtir
      var foto = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('postlar')
          .doc('${id.id}')
          .collection('kullaniciFotograflari')
          .orderBy('tarih', descending: true)
          .limit(3)
          .get();
      //Getirilen fotograflar listeye eklenir.
       if (foto.docs.length > 1) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= foto.docs.length; i++) {
        fotoUrller.add(foto.docs[i].data()["postUrl"]);
        debugPrint("URL"+foto.docs[i].data()["postUrl"]);
        }
      }
    }
   return fotoUrller;
  }
```

Comment: Where is the declaration for the ``fotoUrller``?

Comment: I defined it inside the state class

Comment: `docs.forEach((element) async` [immediately looks wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63719805/) .

Comment: @jamesdlin  The values I want are coming in correctly, I just can't return them

Comment: Right, you can't return them because you *can't properly wait for them* before returning.  Read the linked answer from my previous comment for why using `.forEach` with an `async` callback is almost always wrong.

Comment: ı didnt use forEch but still not working

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with the updated code.  Can you double-check that you tested the updated code?  You should now be observing that that the callbacks print *before* the value is returned (whereas previously they would have printed *after*) Can you provide a minimal, reproducible example?  You also should enable the [unawaited_futures lint](https://dart-lang.github.io/linter/lints/unawaited_futures.html).

Comment: problem solved thanks -jamesdlin

Comment: @YalçınYıldırım Can you please post the solution as an answer for more visibility so that other people with the same issue can get help out of it ?