# Using async/await in "forEach" and "for" in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I recently was trying to do something like this,

**NOTE**: Focus on the print statements.

```
  List shipped = [], pending = [], completed = [], returned = [];
  List<OrderModel> mainOrdersList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }

  Future getData() async {
    var results = await DatabaseHandler().fetchOrders("merchantId");
    results.docs.forEach((f) async {
      var products = await DatabaseHandler().fetchOrderedProducts(f.id);
      var productData = products.data();
      //add to mainOrdersList
      print("mainOrderList Length - ${mainOrdersList.length}");
    });
    //THE BELOW STATEMENT IS BEING EXCECUTED BEFORE THE COMPLETION OF THE FOR LOOP GIVEN ABOVE
    segregate();
    setState(() {});
  }

  void segregate() {
    print("segregating");
    for (int i = 0; i < mainOrdersList.length; i++) {
      mainOrdersList[i].productList.forEach((element) {
        //segregate on the basis of status like pending, shipped, completed, returned
      });
    }
  }
```

**OUTPUT WITH FOREACH -**

```
segregating
mainOrdersList Length - 10
```

Even though I am using `await` in forEach, still the statement below the forEach is being exceuted first. But if I use simple for loop, this doesn't happen and the code works perfectly as it should.

Replacing `forEach` with `for`,

```
  for (int i = 0; i < results.docs.length; i++) {
      var f = results.docs[i].data();
      var products = await DatabaseHandler().fetchOrderedProducts(f.id);
      var productData = products.data();
      //add to mainOrdersList
      print("mainOrderList Length - ${mainOrdersList.length}");
    }
```

**OUTPUT WITH SIMPLE FOR -**

```
mainOrdersList Length - 10
segregating
```

And I also observed that `forEach` was a bit faster than `for`.

Comment: I think this is the best explanation for your problem. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63719374/how-to-wait-for-foreach-to-complete-with-asynchronous-callbacks

Comment: But I'm observing one thing, when I used forEach the list was updated very fast, but now after using normal for loop, the process is slower.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

default forEach not async operation, you must replace it with :

```dart
await Future.forEach(elements, (element) async {
  await element.someThing();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try with a simple login.

```
Future getData() async {
bool isAsyncComplete = false; //add this line
    var results = await DatabaseHandler().fetchOrders("merchantId");
    results.docs.forEach((f) async {
      var products = await DatabaseHandler().fetchOrderedProducts(f.id);
      var productData = products.data();
      //add to mainOrdersList
      print("mainOrderList Length - ${mainOrdersList.length}");
      
      isAsyncComplete = true; //add this line
    
     });
    //THE BELOW STATEMENT IS BEING EXCECUTED BEFORE THE COMPLETION OF THE FOR LOOP GIVEN ABOVE 
     if(isAsyncComplete){. //add this line
         segregate();
         setState(() {});
     }
  
  }
```