# Function not waiting for an async function

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await, flutter-futurebuilder

I need that the function _get_datos_restaurante() waits to the other functions (_get_nombre_provincia() and _get_valoracion_media() ) ends, but I can't achieve that.
The issue is the variable valoracion_media is not correctly "operated" when _get_datos_restaurate() ends. The functions are asynchronous and I am using _get_datos_restaurante() in a FutureBuilder, so I don't know what it's the error.
Here is my code:

```
Future<void> _get_datos_restaurante(String id, QueryDocumentSnapshot r) async {
 await _get_nombre_provincia(id);
  await _get_valoracion_media(r);
  print(valoracion_media);
}

Future<void> _get_nombre_provincia(String id) async {
  await firestoreInstance.collection('Provincia').doc(id).get().then((value) => nombreProvincia = value.get('nombre'));
}

Future<void> _get_valoracion_media(QueryDocumentSnapshot r) async {
  List<dynamic> id_valoraciones = r.get('valoraciones');
  List<double> nota_valoraciones = [];
  id_valoraciones.forEach((v) async {
    await firestoreInstance.collection('Valoracion_Restaurante').doc(v).get().then((value) { 
      nota_valoraciones.add(value.get('nota'));
  });});
  nota_valoraciones.forEach((n) =>valoracion_media+=n);
  valoracion_media = valoracion_media/nota_valoraciones.length;  
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63719374/how-to-wait-for-foreach-to-complete-with-asynchronous-callbacks/63719805#63719805

Answer (score 2):

Use a for loop instead of `forEach` like so:

```
 for(final v in  id_valoraciones){
   final x = await firestoreInstance.collection('Valoracion_Restaurante').doc(v).get();
   nota_valoraciones.add(x.get('nota'));
 }
```

Comment: This is a great answer! Notice that this gets one document at a time whereas [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71497611/1080564) parallelizes getting the documents, so it may take less time but may also stress the system more if there are lots of documents. Use whatever fits your use case :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have a forEach loop where you iterate over `id_valoraciones` which cannot wait for Futures to complete.

In order to wait for several futures at once, you can use [`Future.wait`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future/wait.html), which waits for several futures to complete and collect the results.

You can use [`map`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/map.html) for turning a list of items into a list of Futures, which can then be waited for.

```dart
nota_valoractiones = await Future.wait(id_valoraciones.map((v) async {
  const value = await firestoreInstance.collection('Valoracion_Restaurante').doc(v).get();
  return value.get('nota');
});
```

This code can be broken down as follows:

- For each entry in `id_valoraciones`, create a Future that...

  - Gets a document `value` from firestore
  - Returns the `nota` field from that document
- Waits for all the Futures to complete, saving the results of them in the list `nota_valoractiones`.

In other words, the Futures execute *in parallel*.

As highlighted by [@pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink) in a comment to the question, you [can also use `Future.forEach`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63719374/how-to-wait-for-foreach-to-complete-with-asynchronous-callbacks/63719805#63719805) to perform an asynchronous action for each entry in a list. **Note, however, that [`Future.forEach`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future/forEach.html) does not execute in parallel.**

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know that information :)