# Flutter async function await not awaiting

Tags: flutter, http, asynchronous

I have an async function to upload a video using MultipartRequest:

```
static Future<bool> uploadVideo(File video) async {

var uri = Uri.parse('https://example.com/uploadFile');

Map<String, String> headers = {
"Content-Type": "application/json",
'Accept': 'application/json',
};

var request = http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);
request.headers.addAll(headers);

Uint8List data = await video.readAsBytes();
List<int> list = data.cast();

request.files.add(
await http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('File', list, filename: '.mp4'),
);

final response = await request.send();

if (response.statusCode == 200) {

    return true;
}

return false;
```

when I call the function by:

```
Future<List<File>> files;

    print("--1--");

    files.then((videos) {

      videos.forEach((video) async {
        
        // this call must be await but is not
        await uploadVideo(video);

      });
     print("--2--");

    });

    print("--3--");
```

The console show:

--1--

--3--

--2--

This indicates that await function not await, What's the reason?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63719374/how-to-wait-for-foreach-to-complete-with-asynchronous-callbacks/63719805#63719805

Comment: btw why dont you use [MultipartFile](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/MultipartFile/MultipartFile.html) or [MultipartFile.fromPath](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/MultipartFile/fromPath.html)? that way you dont have to read all the video file content into memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code

```
    List<File> videos = await files;
    print("--1--");
    for (var video in videos) {
      await uploadVideo(video);
      print("--2--");
    }
    print("--3--");
  }
```

--1-- wating files

--2-- uploading video (--2-- Will be printed several times )

--3-- finished

Comment: Would please explain *why* this code works, as opposed to the one shared by the OP?