# How do I pause execution of async forEach function in dart?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I have some folders in Firebase with some files in them. I want to get the download links of one file from each of the folders and store them for later use. I want to store them in a Map such that each download link will be referenced by a key (the Firebase folder name it was from) in the map.

here is the code:

```
Map<String,String>? _data; // _data is already populated before calling _editData

void _editData()
{
  Reference reference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();

  _data?.forEach((key, value) async {
     String url = await Future.delayed(
       const Duration(seconds: 3),
       (() =>  reference.child('$key/$value').getDownloadURL())
     );
     _data?.update(key, (value) => url)
  });

  print('data: $_data');
}
```

But it it seems like this approach is not working because when I print _data, it does not have the url's in it, its not updated. I have to run the function again for the url's to be saved into the map. How can I do this properly?

Comment: hi perhaps might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63719374/how-to-wait-for-foreach-to-complete-with-asynchronous-callbacks