# Dart: Future Map await or what?

Tags: dart

`downloadfile` is declared `void`. A function `encode()` should be executed when the foreach-loop `downloadfile(...)` has ended. How?

```dart
void main() async {
  List<String> urld;
  urld = await get_vid();
  await Future.wait(urld.asMap(), (i, s) async {await downloadfile(s, i.toString());})  // doens't work
  urld.asMap().forEach((i, s) {downloadfile(s, i.toString());}); // the original
  encode();  // should only be executed if all downloadfile-threads are finished.
}
```

Comment: 1. Fix `downloadFile` to return a `Future` instead of `void`. 2. `Future.wait` expects an `Iterable` of `Future`s, so you need to do something like: `await Future.wait([for (var (i, s) in urld.indexed) downloadfile(s, i.toString())]);`

Comment: Also see: [How to wait for forEach to complete with asynchronous callbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63719374/)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that.

If `downloadfile` returns `void`, and doesn't take any callbacks as arguments, then there is no way to known when it's done, because it's not telling. (Unless it's entirely synchronous, in which case it's done when it returns. Since you're asking, I'm assuming that is not the case.)

You should not assume that it actually returns a `Future` typed as `void`. It may, and it may stop doing that tomorrow. Don't try to look behind the `void` veil, it's for your own protection.

So, you need to change `downloadfile` to return a `Future` which completes when it's done, or take an callback like `, {void Function()? onDone}` which is called when done. The former, returning a `Future`, is preferable because it works with the language `await` feature.

Assuming that's the case, then:

```dart
await urld.indexed.map((p) => downloadFile(p.$2, p.$1.toString())).wait;
```

or

```dart
await urld.asMap.entries.map((e) => downloadFile(e.value, p.key.toString())).wait;
```

should work.